# Site bandwidth limit and request time set at sandbox values in a production org - increase via support request?

Tags: force.com-sites, governorlimits, licenses

Just noticed that a customer's (enterprise) production org has in the "24-Hour Usage History" panel of a Force.com Site:

- Bandwidth Limit: 1 GB
- Service Request Time: 30 minutes

These correspond to the sandbox values shown in the [Salesforce Limits Quick
Reference Guide](https://na15.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf) rather than the much higher production values. The customer has just started using Force.com Sites so will probably hit these limits pretty quickly.

Is it normal that these values default to the sandbox values? (This org did start out as a Trialforce org.) Is all that is needed to increase then a support request?

Comment: I've created a case on this with Salesforce and will post the answer I receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Salesforce support:

```
Our tier-3 support has corrected the limits as per defaults. So now the limits for your Org are
- Origin Bandwidth 40 GB for production
- Request Time 60 hours
```

So a support request was all that was needed to change them, though why they were set to a low value remains unclear.